# What does `class =` inside template mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I found this construct in C-code:

```
template<typename T, class = decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>())>
struct check : std::true_type {};
```

Now I understand what it does but I don't understand how it works. It throws a compile error if type `T` doesn't support the `<`-operator. But, apparently, when changing `class` to something else, the whole thing won't compile and throws a Syntax Error.

What does `class = sometypename` mean?

Comment: Default template argument.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, A default template argument without a name?

Comment: I got it 2 seconds after posting.... thanks Captain!

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes, a defaulted template argument without a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class` is the same as `typename` here.  You could also do this:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>())>
struct check : std::true_type {};
```

You can specify default values for template arguments. For example

```
template<typename X = int> struct test { };
```

You can also leave off the name of the template arguments if you don't use them:

```
template<typename = int> struct test { };
```

So in your example, the second template parameter is just an unnamed parameter with a default argument.

Comment: How is the second template parameter referred to in the actual code?

Comment: @merlin2011: it's not referred to. it's a SFINAE check for existence of `<` operator for the type.

Comment: Is not. Is there to check if T have a valid < operator (or to SFINAE this struct if don't have the correct operator).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf How would he specialize for `false_type`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: I don't think you can do that directly, but you can use `check<T>` as a formal argument type for a dummy defaulted argument, to direct overload resolution between two functions.

Answer (score 1):

The concept that makes this work is known as *SFINAE* (substitution failure is not an error) and is used to implement `std::enable_if<>` etc.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae